# NSRangeException in loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm still learning by doing, so please, if this sounds like a noob question, that's probably what it is.

I'm trying to iterate through a NSDictionary (messeges) and grab the value on a certain key.

When I run this code I get the following error"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'"

```
NSArray* keys = [messages allKeys];

int count = [keys count] ;
for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
  for(NSString* key in keys) {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"messagesinconversation"]) {
        NSArray* arr = [messages objectForKey:key];
        NSString *sentby = [[arr valueForKey:@"sentby"] objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog (@"%@", sentby);

    }
}
}
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Should be an issue with your for statement looping....[for (int i=0; i < count; i++)]

NSlog the 'count variable' and 'i' variable

Comment: Why `[[arr valueForKey:@"sentby"] objectAtIndex:i];` as `i` has no relation to the `arr` array, it's an index into the `keys` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem occured in

```
NSString *sentby = [[arr valueForKey:@"sentby"] objectAtIndex:i];
```

May be the arr array count is lessthan keys array count. But you are running the for loop based on the keys count. Replace

```
NSString *sentby = [[arr valueForKey:@"sentby"] objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog (@"%@", sentby);
```

code with below code

```
for(NSDictionary *dictionary in arr){
   NSString *sentby=[dictionary objectForKey:@"sentby"];
   NSLog(@"sentby is %@",sentby);
}
```

Comment: Why not `NSArray *sentBy = [arr valueForKey:@"sentby"];`?

Comment: I finally had a chance to test your code. This did it for me. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is your running two loops

Check this,

```
NSArray* keys = [messages allKeys];

int count = [keys count] ;
for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
    NSString *key=[keys objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"messagesinconversation"])
        {
            NSArray* arr = [messages objectForKey:key];
            NSString *sentby = [[arr valueForKey:@"sentby"] objectAtIndex:i];

            NSLog (@"%@", sentby);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to get value on `objectAtIndex` in this array.So please see my edited code

```
NSArray* keys = [messages allKeys];
  for(NSString* key in keys)
  {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"messagesinconversation"])
    {
        NSArray* arr = [messages objectForKey:key];
        NSString *sentby = [arr valueForKey:@"sentby"]; // here's your problem. 

        NSLog (@"%@", sentby);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you want to do, but the root cause is the fact that `i` is the current index into the `keys` array, not the `arr` array.

Perhaps you want:

```
NSArray *inconversation = [messages objectForKey:@"messagesinconversation"];
if (inconversation) {
    NSArray *sentBy = [inconversation valueForKey:@"sentby"];
    for (NSString *sender in sentBy) {
        NSLog (@"%@", sender);
    }
}
```

(why bother iterating through the dictionary keys when you want one specific element anyway?)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is  NSString *sentby = [[arr valueForKey:@"sentby"] objectAtIndex:i];

i is greater than array count, check the i value and array count .

better make a if condition when retrieving the value

if (i <= [array count]) like this